# Need to run chromium as normal user from root script

Tags: bash, sudo, chromium

I have a kiosk that shuts down every day using rtcwake, and this uses root user. I've used && to execute the boot script after rtcwake completes, however it then starts the browser as root causing problems.

This is the command I use:
`echo debian | sudo -S rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d '3 days 7:45') && sudo -u debian -i bash $HOME/kiosk/bin/startup.sh &`.

The sudo command does work to some extent. It calls the debian user, and executes the correct script, however, it still screws up my chromium preferences.

Here is the startup script:

```
echo debian | sudo -S hwclock -w

export HOME=/home/debian

#log boot time

echo "Booting at" $(date) >> $HOME/kiosk/bin/logs/boot.log


#echo debian | sudo -S service connman restart


echo debian | sudo -S at 15:30 -f $HOME/kiosk/bin/shutdown.sh

crontab -u debian crontab.txt

bash $HOME/git.sh

#sudo -i -u debian

#start kiosk

export DISPLAY=:0
chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-gpu 
http://localhost/kiosk/Client/main.html &

#update ip
bash /home/debian/git.sh &
```

I'm wondering what could be causing chrome to be executed as root. I have no idea what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must enter a password to log into a new user shell.

The command needs to be modified as follows:

```
echo debian | sudo -S rtcwake -m mem -u -t $(date +%s -d '3 days 7:45') && echo debian | sudo -S -u debian -i bash $HOME/kiosk/bin/startup.sh &
```

This avoids needing a password to log in as normal Debian user, and executes the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you execute a command with `sudo` it will not change environment variables like `$HOME`. Since per user settings are stored in `$HOME`, this affects the executed program if it needs such configuration files. Check this for example:

```
sudo -u debian bash -c 'echo $HOME'
```

It will print the home folder of the calling user, not the home folder of the user specified trough `-u`. The `sudo` command supports the `-H` command line option to handle this, however if it works depends on the security police in use.

As a solution you can use the `su` command instead of `sudo` in this case:

```
... && su debian -c chromium
```

Since `su` itself is executed by `root` you won't be asked for the password.

Comment: I already am sudoing into the Debian user. Since I'm using $HOME for the scripts path, the script won't be executed unless it's the correct user.

Comment: Su vs sudo doesn't make any difference. It is reacting in exactly the same way. Sudo has a -I option that's accomplished the same thing. I have tested this